# Is it possible to create a google form that automatically updates its questions from a google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I have a google sheet that logs a list of names from another spread sheet 3x per week.

I'm trying to make a google form that updates its questions 3x per week from the data being generated by the logsheet and to skip creating a question for a cell that does not contain any data. At the end of the week (every 3rd submission) I want the form to total the number of questions answered "yes" and send an email with the number to several people. I'm trying to format the question as indicated below.

"Was a sample for (Name) collected today?"
-yes
-no

I havent tried anything in terms of creating the questions, Im new to coding and I havent been able to find any sample text that quite fits.

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data Sheet');
 var RDSheet = ss.getSheetByName('RawDataSheet');
 var lastrowdata = RDSheet.getLastRow();
 var RawData = sourceSheet.getRange(45,1,1,34);

 RDSheet.getRange(lastrowdata + 1, 1).setValue(new Date()); // Insert 
 timestamp for raw data
 RawData.copyTo(RDSheet.getRange(lastrowdata + 1, 2), {contentOnly: false});
```

I want to create a form that updates automatically from a google sheet and generates an email based off results.

Comment: It's possible to create a script that reads a Google Spreadsheet and creates a Google Form from that information.

Answer (score 0):

1. To update the Form questions dynamically from a Spreadsheet, you need to assign values from cells in the sheet as parameters to titles and choices of the questions.

Here is a code snippet based on the [Form Service References](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) that :

```
function myFunction() {
    var form = FormApp.openById('Id of your form');
    var spreadsheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById('Id of your Spreadsheet');      
    form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, spreadsheet.getId());
    var source=spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange().getValues();
    var item = form.addCheckboxItem();
    item.setTitle(source[0][0]);          
    item.setChoices([item.createChoice((source[0][1])),item.createChoice((source[0][2]))]);
    form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
        .setTitle((source[1][0]))
        .setChoiceValues([(source[1][1]), (source[1][2])])
        .showOtherOption(true);
    form.addDateItem()
        .setTitle((source[2][0]));        
    Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
    Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());
}
```

2. To evaluate the form responses, please have a look at the [Class FormResponse reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response).

Here is a code snippet based on the reference sample that implements a `YesCounter` variable. It loops through the queston of itnerest for all form submissions and increments `YesCounter` for all answers where the response to the question was "yes".

```
var YesCounter=0;
var formResponses = form.getResponses();
for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
  var formResponse = formResponses[i];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
 //assuming the question of interest is question number 1:
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[0];
    if(itemResponse.getResponse()=='yes'){
     YesCounter++
    }  
}
Logger.log('The number of questions answered "yes" was: '+Yescounter);
```

3. You can [install](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)  a [time-based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#timeBased()) and link it to a function that counts the "yes" and sends an email at time intervals of your choice.
   [image]
4. If you are not comfortable using Apps Script, there are also useful Add-ons available (use at your own discretion), for example here is one that implements Dynamic Field Update automatically:

https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/dynamic_fields/708020008404